# Updating ESP32 firmware from another ESP32 over USB, similar to how esptool.py works

Tags: esp32

Is there a way to update the firmware on one ESP32 from another ESP32 over USB, similar to how firmware can be updated using esptool.py?

This would essentially be like a port of whatever magic esptool.py uses over USB to update an ESP32, but instead of running through Python it would be an Arduino C++ sketch and would read the firmware to write to the other ESP32 from SPIFFS.

Comment: since ESP32 doesn't have an USB peripheral on chip, a better idea would be to that over the UART. did you research before asking? did you find something? did you try something?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion, @Juraj.  However, all of the ESP32s that I am working with include a CP2102 USB to UART bridge.

Comment: can CP2102 act as USB host? no.

Comment: That's a great point, @Juraj

Comment: you know that you can use OTA upload?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SD card to update the firmware.
Here is the example [code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/examples/SD_Update/SD_Update.ino)

Answer (score 0):

The esp32 can update itself. To store and apply the updated sketch's binary it uses the Update library bundled with the ESP32 Arduino boards support package.

Then there are libraries for different ways of transporting the binary over network:

- ArduinoOTA for upload from the Arduino IDE
- HTTPUpdate to download the binary from a web server
- HTTPUpdateServer to upload the binary to ESP32 over a web page

The keyword is "OTA update" as "over the air update" even it is possible to transport the update over cable too.